# VBA Check all options, choose the cheapest

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in my workbook.
the first table (A1:D10) shows all machines which are planed to built on a specific date (AGA Start)
the second table (F1:I10) shwos all storages which are ready to use on a specific date (POS End)

[image]

Every day the storage is not used it costs (in my test 5$ per day). Now i want the macro that it tries all possibilities to distribute the storages to the machines that the cheapest way will be shown.

The following code only shows the costs when TSP1 is used for Machine1 / TSP2 for machine2 / ... / TSP10 for Machine10:

```
Sub TSP_Simulation()
    Dim TSP_Lastrow As Long, Machine_Lastrow As Long
    Dim Day_min() As Long, tsp_nr() As Long, machine_nr() As Long _
, Costs() As Long
    Dim tsp() As String, machine() As String
    Dim size_tsp As Integer, size_machine As Integer, TSP_Costs As Integer, Not_available As Integer
    Dim TSP_Range As Range, machine_Range As Range


    size_tsp = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(6))
    size_machine = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))

    TSP_Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Machine_Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim tsp(size_tsp), machine(size_machine) _
    , tsp_nr(size_tsp), machine_nr(size_machine) _
    , Day_min(size_tsp), Costs(size_machine)

    b = 2
    For a = 2 To TSP_Lastrow
        c = 0
    ' Choose first TSP:
        Set TSP_Range = Cells(a, 8)
        tsp(a) = Cells(a, 6).Value
        tsp_nr(a) = Cells(a, 7).Value

' Check if Machine has no TSP:
        For b = 2 To Machine_Lastrow
            If IsEmpty(Cells(b, 3)) Then
                DayDiff = DateDiff("D", Cells(a, 9).Value, Cells(b, 4).Value)
                If DayDiff < 0 Then
                    c = c + 1
                    GoTo Line1
                End If
                TSP_Costs = DayDiff * 5
                Costs(c) = TSP_Costs
                machine(c) = Cells(b, 1)
                machine_nr(c) = Cells(b, 2)
            Else: GoTo Line1
            End If
            c = c + 1
Line1:  Next b

        y = Application.Min(Costs)
        Range("J" & a) = Costs(y)
        Range("C" & a) = tsp_nr(a)
        TSP_Range.Value = machine_nr(y)
    Next a
End Sub
```

Hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: You might want to google " Excel Solver" for a possible solution

Comment: This is a classic Linear Programming problem that you can do using the solver: objective is to minimise total cost and constraint may be machine capacity... without complete data...